# getting error 500 after trying to add a tab to wordpress customizer

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i'm trying to add a tab to my wordpress customizer.

i use the next code:

```
add_action('customize_register','theme_costumizer_register');

function theme_costumizer_register($wp_customize){
    $wp_customize->add_section('facebook_new_section', array(
            'title'     =>  'Social Media',
            'priority'  =>  10
        ));
    $wp_customize->add_settings('facebook',
        array(
            'default'   =>  'http://facebook.com/ahiad'
        ));
    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Control($wp_customize,'txtFacebookAddress',
        array(
            'label'     =>  'Facebook Link',
            'section'   =>  'facebook_new_section',
            'type'      =>  'text'
            )));


}
```

the problem is every time i run this piece of code in my website, i get an error 500, could not spot the problem here...

Comment: which wordpress version are you using ?

Comment: i'm using 4.9.9 at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$wp_customize->settings` which is not not exists, Please use `$wp_customize->setting`.

**Please try below code :**

```
   add_action('customize_register','theme_costumizer_register');

function theme_costumizer_register($wp_customize){
    $wp_customize->add_section('facebook_new_section', array(
        'title'     =>  'Social Media',
        'priority'  =>  10
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting('facebook',
        array(
            'type' => 'theme_mod', // or 'option'
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
            'theme_supports' => '', // Rarely needed.
            'default'   =>  'http://facebook.com/ahiad',
            'transport' => 'refresh', // or postMessage
            'sanitize_callback' => '',
            'sanitize_js_callback' => '', 

        ));
    $wp_customize->add_control('facebook',
        array(
            'label'     =>  'Facebook Link',
            'section'   =>  'facebook_new_section',
            'type'      =>  'text'
        ));   
}
```

I hope it will helps you. Thanks

Comment: Right answer tested and confirmed !!

Comment: Thanks :) , Please mark as an answer so it help other developers too.

Comment: I have upvoted for your answer but the answer only marked as a acceptable for the question asked person !!

Comment: ohh yes, Thanks :)

Comment: it indeed was the right code, thank you very much!
but can you explain what you did there?
i see that you've added the:

Comment: @dineshkashera 'type', 'capability','theme_supports' etc...

it is to let this function have the permissions to modify the wordpress theme?

Comment: and thank you very much for your answer! @dineshkashera

Comment: @ahiadhazan Please check this url https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API for parameters.